# Tax on non-us iphone developer

Tags: iphone

Apple will hold up to 30% of what they owe you for tax purposes unless you can provide an EIN number to apple to claim the tax treaty benefits.

But the information from this [article](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/06/quick-tip-for-nonus-iphone-dev.html) only applies to developers who operate under a company, so if i am self employed and work individually how can I claim the 30% withholding tax?

Comment: You might want to review and correct the second paragraph. I'd like to help, but I can't quite follow your question.

Comment: I think the question is:

You can register for the iPhone developer program as an individual or a company. If you register as an individual, how do you reclaim the 30% tax withholding that Apple does if you're a foreign (non-US) citizen. You can claim the 30% back by providing an EIN number if you're registered as an organization.

Comment: i have edited the 2 paragraph and make it short and clear enough thanks for help

Comment: thanks rein,that is what i am asking, so if i was not registered as an organization?

Comment: fwiw, this is definitely programming related imho

Comment: Just vote to reopen after the close weenies close it

Answer (score 7):

I'm self employed and based in the UK. You can call the IRS in the US and apply for an EIN. That's what I did. More details in [this forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=529803).

Answer (score 3):

Follow the same steps in the O'Reilly article you linked to... It would be the same process whether you are an organization or an individual.

Apparently you can also just "enter nine zeros (000000000) in the space provided in section 6. In addition, payments from the USA App Store will not be reported to the IRS on form 1042 at year end."

Comment: if my country dont have tax treaty with US,still need  to finish this form?our agreement with apple is sort of sales & commision but not royalty, does it mean actually US wont withhold the tax if we fill up the form?

Comment: As I said, "Apparently you can also just "enter nine zeros (000000000) in the space provided in section 6."